# How to controll the input field value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Redux to manage the state. 
Here we have two conditions: 
We have two input fields here:
lets suppose: **InputField1** and **InputField2**.

FIRST CONDITION:
Now, whenever i change **InputField1** value to, eg: `inputvalue1` then when i click outside the input field, it calls the api to change the store value.
And, it does successfully. And when the store is updated successfully, the InputField1 tag and the InputField2 tag are mapped to updated store accordingly.

SECOND CONDITION:
Let's suppose, when i change the **InputField1** value to `inputvalue1updating` and lets say it is in the process of udpating the store. Now, if i start changing something the InputField2 value, eg:`inputvalue2`. And i am still changing the value. Now, if the InputField1 value is udpated and updated the store. Then what happens is it again maps the updated value i.e. InputField1 to `inputvalue1` and InputField2 to `` (empty) as it was empty in previously.

What I want? 
What I want is whenever i am in any input field and if i am typing or changing. I don't want the updated value to be mapped in the fields.

what I tried. 
I tried to use the onFocus attribute. I tried if the input is in onFocus, it should not change the value but it does not work as it wont let to type anything as well.

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: please share the code.
What comes to the top of my mind is saving the value of what you are presenting in a use Ref. have a store updated value as you have. and then control the Ref whenever you'd like. 
but again, it is hard to explain with no code presented